# Eclipse compiling with JRE or JDK

Tags: java, eclipse, virtual-machine

I have one question in my mind and I should note that I know the differences between JDK and JRE. I am not a new programmer in Java.

What I would like to ask is in Eclipse I can specify the compilation environment (correct me if I a wrong) in window> Preferences but we can also change it for a specific project.

OK. I added jre and jdk folder in the options. I can use both.
But JRE has no javac (no java compiler) in it. So how it is possible that some projects requires that I need to change to jre1.7 to COMPILE?
I was getting some minor.major version error and setting JRE solved my problem?

How can this be possible?

In fact now I realized something.
Ok the question changes a little.
I saw that these are VM not compiler. I understood.

Does JDK have also JRE in it? so if I specify JDK1.8 I am setting jre1.8 as VM and if I specify JRE1.7 I am setting jre1.7 as VM?

Is it right?

It makes confusions. Why JDK has JRE in it?

[image]

Comment: You are compiling with a greater version of java and the using an older jre to run. Watch your classpath setting, not general one. JRE 1.7 or 1.8 will be fine, just make sure to compile with a lower or equal jdk.

Comment: Its also project specific, check configuration in your project, it can override default settings

Answer (score 2):

**JDK has whole JRE (regular Java VM) inside, in order to allow you to run what you will develop with it.**

Theoretically someone could make some small-JDK with just tools and without JRE, but it would make a whole lot more confusion as to which tools version run with which JVM version  (most JDK tools needs JVM to be run). Look at you, how many people have only this problem? So it is bundled together, tools and JRE as a whole named JDK, thanks to that you have some guarantee that those JRE and tools will work together.

**JRE** - Java Runtime Environment - allows you to run java programs

**JDK** - Java Development Kit - allows you to run and develop java programs

**JDK = JRE + tools for developer**

Also note, that You can choose for the java compilation process two things:

compatibility with source version - this is basically the syntax you are allowed to use.

compatibility with VM version - this is the minimum VM level on which you can run the compiled binaries.

example from your post: If you have compiled something as Java 8, you can't run it on Java 7, this is the minor/major version problem you have. But the opposite (to run something for Java 7 on Java 8) is valid.

in your example **JDK8** and **JRE7** both are just fully functional VM's, but JDK8 has additionally (in comparison to JRE) development tools inside it.

Comment: IMHO the main advantage of using the JDK in Eclipse is that Eclipse automatically uses the JavaDoc/Java source code and parameter naming from JDK. AFAIR those values are not available from a standard JRE.